# Rails attr_accessible :object vs :object_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

A `User` `has_one` `Account`.  When setting up `attr_accessible` on the User model is it better to protect `:account`, `:account_id` or both?

```
attr_accessible :account
```

or

```
attr_accessible :account_id
```

or

```
attr_accessible :account, :account_id
```

I feel like both is the way to go (as it's more secure) even though it feel less DRY.

**Update to give more background**

Just to give a bit more background on why I'm asking.  I, like most ppl, saw what happened to Github so we're going through our app and locking it down a little tighter.

In the process of doing this I found tests in which we pass in account

`User.create account: account`

and where we passed in account_id:

`User.create account_id: account.id`

My options were to either change them all to be consistant or change `attr_accessible` to allow either.  I decided to change them all to be consistant.  But this got me worried that we were perhaps using both methods throughout our app and I might break our app by only allowing one or the other.

I did misspeak when I said using both is more secure.  It was a long day.

Comment: Are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as well?

Comment: If the answer to my question depends on the answer to yours, I'd love to see the reason and an answer in both cases.

Comment: If you are using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :account` then rails is going to automatically try to apply and `params[:user][:account_attributes]` when it does the your create or update. In this case you would also need to add `attar_accessible :account_attributes`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no right answer for this one, though it does depend on how you intend to update this user. `attr_accessible :account` will allow you to mass-assign the account directly like this:

```
user.update_attributes(:account => account)
```

Helpful if you already have an account object that you want to associate to the user along with a lot of other attributes. On the other hand, `attr_accessible :account_id` would be more appropriate if you were assigning the account's ID, as from a dropdown or some other form element:

```
user.update_attributes(params[:user]) # params[:user][:account_id] is a part of this hash
```

This latter case is generally considered more dangerous and was part of the problem with Github's recent security issue: that you can post any account_id you like, including an account that doesn't belong to you, and your user will be assigned to it.

So overall I would go for the former and do a look-up to ensure the account is one that you expect, but as I said at the beginning, you can go either way on this one depending on how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you rather set `attr_accessible :user` or `attr_accessible :user_id` in your account.rb, assuming that an account `belongs_to :user`.

Also, `attr_accessible` is an explicit white list. I don't see how `attr_accessible :user, :user_id` would be more secure than `attr_accessible :user`.

Comment: Honestly the specifics if what goes into which model, is irrelevant.  It's more of a general question of which is better.  And yes, I probably misspoke when I said using both is more secure.  I'll add some more detail in my original question.